# sed command: regex in bash to exclude certain strings

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, regex-negation

I want to exclude everything in the clip and the Date but select all other data.

Data:

```
02.04.2001 ERROR (User1) Server can't start
01.02.2005 ERROR (User2) Server can't start
07.08.2006 ERROR (User1) Problem with Login
12.05.2009 ERROR (User2) Problem with Login
```

Desired output:

```
ERROR  Server can't start
ERROR  Server can't start
ERROR  Problem with Login
ERROR  Problem with Login
```

I tried something like this `sed -n "s/^.*ERROR/ERROR/p"` to exclude the Date at the beginning. This worked.

I can't figure out how to exlude the "(User)" string.

Comment: Something [like this maybe](https://ideone.com/kMj8Zv)

Comment: If i use this, it shows me everything except the Datas which match the regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$ sed -n "s/[^)]*ERROR ([^)]*)/ERROR/p" file
ERROR Server can't start
ERROR Server can't start
ERROR Problem with Login
ERROR Problem with Login
```

We have added the regex `([^)]*)` which captures the user string.

Just in case the string `ERROR` might occur more than once in the line, we changed the regex that precedes `ERROR` from `.*` to `[^)]*`.  This prevents the regex from matching to any `ERROR` string that might occur after the `(User1)` string.

Note that the leading `^` was unnecessary.  Sed's regular expression match the leftmost-longest match.  That means that `.*ERROR` will always match starting at the beginning of the line.

Comment: seems like the right solution but i still get some problems. if the line has more string for example "02.04.2001 ERROR [unknown area] (User1) Server can't start" does your regex still work?

Comment: @J.Doe To detect and remove characters between `ERROR` and `(User1)`, try: `sed -n "s/.*ERROR[^)]*([^)]*)/ERROR/p" file`.  This adds `[^)]*' to match any number of non-`)` characters between ERROR and user.

Comment: @J.Doe Imagine a line like `12.05.2009 ERROR (User2) Problem (aa(bb)cc)dd with (ee) ff) Login`

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov The current code handles that line just fine because the regex `[)]*)` will match to the first, not the last, close parens that follows.  There could be a problem if more than one `ERROR` string occurs in the line; I have updated the answer to handle that.

Comment: @John1024, hmm, really? I thought [this](https://ideone.com/FusWUd) is not what he wanted

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov Where did you see that the OP didn't want that?  I did not spot any indication that the OP wanted to change the message that follows the parens-user string.  Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Simply with ***awk***:

```
awk '{ $1=$3=""; sub(/^ */,"",$0) }1' file
```

- `$1=$3=""` - clear the 1st and 3rd field
- `sub(/^ */,"",$0)` - remove excessive spaces at start of line

The output (as your desired output has **2**-spaced separator between the 1st and 2nd item):

```
ERROR  Server can't start
ERROR  Server can't start
ERROR  Problem with Login
ERROR  Problem with Login
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
sed -E 's/^\S+\s+//; s/\(\S+\)//g; s/\s\s*/ /g' file
```

where

- `-E` option enables [ERE syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/ERE-syntax.html#ERE-syntax);
- `s/^\S+\s+//` removes non-whitespace characters followed by one or more whitespace characters (i.e. the date and the spaces after it);
- `s/\(\S+\)//g` removes sequences in parens;
- `s/\s\s*/ /g` replaces duplicate spaces with a single space.

*Test*

```
$ cat sample 
02.04.2001 ERROR (User1) Server can't start
01.02.2005 ERROR (User2) Server can't start
07.08.2006 ERROR (User1) Problem with Login
12.05.2009 ERROR (User2) Problem with Login
12.05.2009 ERROR (User2) Problem (sfsdfsdf(sdfsdf)sdfsf) with (another) aaa) Login
12.05.2009 ERROR (User2) Problem with asdfsdf(sadfasdf) Login
12.05.2009 ERROR (User2) Problem (sfsdfsdf(sdfsdf)sdfsf)aa with (another) aaa) Login

$ sed -E 's/^\S+\s+//; s/\(\S+\)//g; s/\s\s*/ /g' sample
ERROR Server can't start
ERROR Server can't start
ERROR Problem with Login
ERROR Problem with Login
ERROR Problem with aaa) Login
ERROR Problem with asdfsdf Login
ERROR Problem aa with aaa) Login
```

---

Almost the same using Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/^\S+\s+//; s/\(\S+\)//g; s/\s{2,}/ /g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

In awk. `gsub` would've been easier but I had a point for using `match` which I forgot (:

```
$ awk '
{
    while(match($0,/(^| )(([0-9]{2}\.){2}[0-9]{4}|\([^)]*\))($| )/))
        $0=(RSTART==1?"":substr($0,1,RSTART)) substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}1' file
ERROR Server can't start
ERROR Server can't start
ERROR Problem with Login
ERROR Problem with Login
```

It searches for (given kind of) dates with `match` (don't we all :) and parenthesized strings and `substr`s around them.